# Pegar id em tempo real Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

Estou criando um novo documento no firebase e gosta de pegar o id que vou estar criando para salvar na minha coleção, porém como eu faria para pegar o mesmo se ainda não salvei no banco de dados?

Exemplo: o id que vai gerar vai ser Iq313NGP4V6jrjdlWn4T, gostaria de conseguir salvar isso numa variavel e passar para o cd_id no .set.

```
var novoProduto = db.collection("/caminho").doc();

                novoProduto.set({
                    cd_categoria: categoria,
                    cd_id: 'aqui gostaria de ter o id',
                    ds_descricao: descricao,
                    ds_nome: nome,
                    modalidade: "1",
                    nr_preco: preco

                })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
  var novo_id = firebase.database().ref().child('caminho').push().key;

  firebase.database().ref('caminho/' + novo_id).set({
         cd_categoria: categoria,
         cd_id: novo_id,
         ds_descricao: descricao,
         ds_nome: nome,
         modalidade: "1",
         nr_preco: preco
  });
```